# Sending to Service Bus Event Hubs from a WCF Message Inspector

Tags: web-services, wcf, endpoints, idispatchmessageinspector, azure-eventhub

I've got a working web service and test client and i can intercept the messages between them. but when i add the code to send to my event hub the client shows a fault:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The argument Endpoints is null or empty.

Parameter name: Endpoints
```

The more detailed exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:    The argument Endpoints is null or empty.
Parameter name: Endpoints (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail,  likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.ArgumentException: The argument Endpoints is null or empty.
Parameter name: Endpoints
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder.Validate()
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()
at  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationManager.
Initialize(String connection, Nullable`1 transportType)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationManager.
.ctor(Nullable`1 transportType)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventHubClient.Create(String path)
at WCFInterceptor.MessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(Message& request,  ICli
entChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
at  System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.AfterReceiveReques
tCore(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(Me
ssageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatc...).
```

And heres the code i add:

```
try
        {
            NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(GetServiceBusConnectionString());
            Manage.CreateEventHub(hubName, 16, namespaceManager);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetupEHError" + e);
        }
        EventHubClient client = EventHubClient.Create(hubName);
        Console.WriteLine("eventhubclient iniciado");
        EventData messageData = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedString));

        try
        {
            client.Send(messageData);
            Console.WriteLine("MessageData enviada");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("ErrorMessage:" + e);
        }
```

Here is the CreateEventHub Method:

```
public static void CreateEventHub(string eventHubName, int        numberOfPartitions, NamespaceManager manager)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the Event Hub
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Event Hub...");
            EventHubDescription ehd = new EventHubDescription(eventHubName);
            ehd.PartitionCount = numberOfPartitions;
            manager.CreateEventHubIfNotExistsAsync(ehd).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Created");
        }
        catch (AggregateException agexp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(agexp.Flatten());
        }
    }
```

The WebService Console App prints up to

```
Creating Event Hub
Created
```

So i was thinking i might need to add Endpoints for the MessageInspector in the WebService to be able to send data to a Service Bus Event Hub. if so, how is the configuration?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you using the key of the service bus or the event hub , have you added a manage permission to your event hub ??

Comment: its a manage permission from my event hub yes

Comment: I had the same issue but i figured out i was using the key of my service hub instead of my event hub , i let down the SDK and implemented my own Simple event hub create function  using The Rest API and it worked

Comment: if you dismissed the sdk and used http posts to send your events to the hub, how did you deal with the SAS key issue? since it has a TIL

Comment: i would prefer using the sdk if it is possible to do so in my situation ( having the inspector do the message sending ). Also you sure there isn't any need for an endpoint, because of the" endpoints argment is null or invalid "? if that makes any sense

Comment: considering your output the problem is not with send since it s not printing eventhubclient iniciado, and there is no need for an endpoint for service bus , i have used it many times

Comment: have you been able to use the sdk in this situation? i would greatly prefer it over http messages. And any idea on how to troubleshoot my exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background**:

ServiceBus SDK has 2 major interfaces:

1. NamespaceManager: for all Management operations (`aka Control Plane`) like Create Delete Topics/EHubs etc
2. EntityClients (TopicClient, EventHubClient etc) : for runtime operations (`aka Data Plane`) - to Send/Recv from Topics/EventHubs.

Both these interfaces will need their own connection strings for connecting to ServiceBus. For ex: The connection string specified to NamespaceManager will need ManageClaims and for EntityClients will just need Send/Recv claims.

You created EventHubClient with just EventHub Name and didn't pass connection string there. In this case, the above error is thrown from our ServiceBus client sdk - when the connection string is not passed via app.config.
To fix this, change this line (as you are using ConnectionString directly for NamespaceManager and not using any app.config):

```
EventHubClient client = EventHubClient.Create(hubName);
```

Change it to:

```
----edit-----
    var eHubConnStr = GetServiceBusConnectionString();
    eHubConnStr.EntityPath = eventHubName;
    // Evaluate here, if you have to populate the Security related properties from the ConnectionString
    // eHubConnStr.SasKey and SasKeyName to Send only or Recv only
----edit-----
    EventHubClient client = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(eHubConnStr); // this connection string should be the EventHub Send conn str.
```

HTH! Sree

Comment: I've done those changes but now i get a diferent error:   Event
Hub name should be specified as EntityPath in connectionString.
Parameter name: entityPath (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely
created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.ArgumentNullException: EventHub name should be specified as EntityPath in
 connectionString.
Parameter name: entityPath
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(S
tring connectionString)

Answer (score -1):

Actually all i needed to do was editing the app config of my web service server with the connection string. seems like the Create method of the eventhubclient takes the eventhub name and then goes to the appconfig for the key, thus so it wasn't finding it.

Comment: One drawback with this approach is - the NamespaceMgr - which is used to create EventHub and the EventHubClient which is used for Runtime operations are using the same security key! This is usually fine for a small sample services, but for any production ready code - I would recommend isolation of Security roles. You may look at the latest edit - which can help achieve that.